# ¿Como enviar un array de javascript a un correo ya sea por php o por otra tecnología?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, phpmailer

Tengo un arreglo general que contiene varios arreglos en los cual almaceno la informacón que haya seleccionado el usuario de varios pasos de un cotizador, el cual es el siguiente:

```
var seleccGeneral = [{"Paso 1": selectEmpStar},{"Paso 2": selectEtapa},{"Paso 3": selectServ},{"Paso 4": selectCarac},{"Paso 5": selectCuent},{"Paso 6": selecDatos}];
```

Mi pregunta es como toda esa data la envío a un correo? ya sea media php o otra tecnología.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más común en estos casos, cuando se necesita enviar datos al back-end (ya sea Java, PHP, Python, etc.) es usar AJAX.

Revisa los siguientes enlaces, pueden darte una idea de como solucionar tu problema.

- [Ejemplo AJAX, JQuery y PHP](https://www.imaginanet.com/blog/usando-ajax-un-simple-ejemplo-con-php-y-jquery.html)
- [JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)